Hint for solving a PDE
Consider
$$u_x +\frac{x}{y}[1-(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)]u_{y}=h, $$
where f,  g, h are the real functions of x.
**My attempt: **
The characteristic equations in the nonparametric form are
$$\frac{dx}{1}=  \frac{dy}{\frac{x}{y}[1-(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)]}= \frac{du}{h}. $$
From
$$\frac{dx}{1}=  \frac{dy}{\frac{x}{y}[1-(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)]},$$
we get
$$\frac{d(x^2- y^2)}{dx}= 2x- 2y \frac{dy}{dx}= 2x(x^2-y^2)(f y^2 + 2g). $$
putting $w = x^2- y^2$,  we get the Bernoulli equation as follows
$$\frac{dw}{dx}- 2x(2g + f x^2) w =-2xf w^2.$$
Solving the above equation we obtain
$$\frac{1}{w} e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}- \int 2xf e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}dx= c_0.$$
Hence
$$w = \frac{e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}}{\int 2xf e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}dx + c_0}.$$
Also we can see that
$$\frac{x dx}{x} = \frac{y dy}{x - x w (fy^2 + 2g)} = \frac{du}{h},$$
which concludes
$$\frac{xdx - y dy}{xw(fy^2+ 2g)} = \frac{du}{h}.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{d (x^2- y^2)}{2x(x^2- y^2)(f y^2 + 2g)}=  \frac{du}{h}, $$
which means
$$\frac{du}{h}= \frac{dw}{2xw(f x^2+ 2g) - 2xfw^2}.$$
Putting w in the above relation and some simplifications gets
$$d u = h dx.$$
Then there is a constant such that
$$u = \int h dx + c_1.$$
Then the general solution is as follows
$$\Omega\Big(\frac{1}{w} e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}- \int 2xf e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}dx , u - \int h dx\Big) = 0,$$
for any function $\Omega$. From above equality, one could imply
$$u = \Lambda \big(\frac{1}{w} e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}- \int 2xf e^{\int 2x(2g+ f x^2)dx}dx\big) + \int h dx,$$
where $\Lambda$ is a differentiable real function of one variable.
Is the above solution is correct?
Thanks for any help.
